# How to customize large dimension processing using ProcessAdd in SSAS?

Tags: ssas, cube, dimension

We have a very large dimension in our SSAS. During the incremental run we are using ProcessAdd to process the dimension. This dimension processing is taking 95 % of the total cube processing time.

This dimension involves single table. The named query for the dimension from DSV is -

```
  SELECT        ABC, XYZ, DEF, PQR, PLADKey, LEFT(ABC, 3) AS DNL1, LEFT(ABC, 7) AS DNL2, 
                         LEFT(ABC, 9) AS DNL3
FROM            dbo.PLAD AS ad
```

The table has more than 33000000 rows that increases daily. Is it possible that due to high row count the processAdd is working slow. Does it automatically picks the news rows only or do we have to specify the filter criteria to identify new rows ( like adding a where condition to select only the data that is greater than last key value)?

We are using AMO to generate the XMLA script for processing. If we need to add filters how we do that in AMO?

We are working on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Any suggestions that could improve the performance for this dimension processing will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your current state you ran a ProcessAdd on that dimension but didn't customize the query to just read the new rows? First, it is important to only do ProcessAdd on dimensions which are insert-only (no updates or deletes) in your ETL. If that's your case then I blogged about ProcessAdd [here](http://www.artisconsulting.com/blogs/greggalloway/2007/4/20/processadd-examples). See the "ProcessAdd Dimension 2008.xmla" example. It shows how to provide a SQL query that only returns the new rows.

Comment: Hi Greg, Thanks for your inputs. I read your blog. I have a question - from section 2. ProcessAdd Dimension - Point 3 - "In BIDS, open the data source view ...." when I do this it brings the code for every other dimension and facts. Do I need to select only the part for my large dimension.

Comment: @AJ01 the out-of-line DSV must contain the tables required for all dimensions or partitions being processed which use that DSV normally. I don't think it hurts to have extra DSV tables but you can try cleaning unnecessary ones up if you like

Comment: @GregGalloway hi, could you help me in the very similar problem please? :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51286842/amo-olap-querybinding?noredirect=1#comment89552187_51286842